# CSS/jQuery- how to change the css of a class with toggle

Tags: jquery, css, icons, toggle

I created a listview which toggle once I click on ".toggle-post".There is an icon inside the div in . The icon is an arrow which suppose to change to another icon once the listview is toggled.

```
   $('[data-postas]').click(function changeHeader(event){
        var element = $(event.srcElement);
        $('.toggle-post').text(element.text());
        $('#postAs').val(element.attr('data-postas'));
        if(element.attr('data-company')){
                $('#company').val(element.attr('data-company'));

        }

        $('.icon-cheack').remove();
        element.append('<i class="icon-cheack fright"></i>');
          setTimeout(function() {
        $(".ul-post").toggle();
        }, 500);
        $('#dropdownIcon').addClass('ui-icon-dropdown');
        })


$(".toggle-post").click(function(){
         $(".ul-post").toggle();


  });

 <fieldset style="display: inline" >
                <div style="display: inline">
                <div class="text-light" style="float: left" >Post as: </div>
                <div class="link toggle-post" style="float: right" >Yourself<span id="dropdownIcon" class="ui-icon-dropdown"></span></div>
                </div>
                %{--<div data-role="collapsible"  data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right">--}%
                    %{--<h3 id="listHeader">Yourself</h3>--}%
                    <ul class="ul-post" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" style="width: 240%; display:none">
                        <li data-postas="0">Yourself</li>
                        <g:if test="${companyList?.size() > 1}">
                            <li style="background-color: #CCCCCC">As your company</li>
                            <g:each var="company" in="${companyList}">
                                <li data-postas="1" value="${company?.id}" id="${company?.companyname}" data-company="${company?.id}">${company?.companyname}</li>
                            </g:each>
                         </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <input type="hidden" value="${companyList[0].id}" name="company"/>
                        </g:else>

                    </ul>

            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the jQuery docs, `toggle()` will:

> Display or hide the matched elements.

So, basically, `toggle()` would be the wrong approach for classes. You need to use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead.

```
$(".toggle-post").click(function(){
    $(".ul-post").toggleClass( "someClass" );
});
```

### Based on your edit:

```
#myIcon {
    background: url("some/url/icon.png") no-repeat;
}
#myIcon.someClass {
    background: url("some/different/url/icon.png") no-repeat;
}
```

So then you would toggle the "someClass" class on and off, and ta da!

Comment: but how can I replace each time to the second icon? Plus how it supposed to be done in the first case of the toggle (I edited the question)?